# Jetpack Compose with Material 3: NavigationDrawer - add route to NavigationDrawerItem

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer

im learning Jetpack Compose with Material 3. My Testapplication has a **ModalNavigationDrawer** now, which works fine. But the problem is, that every time, when im on the HomeScreen and i click the Icon for the HomeScreen, another instance of HomeScreen gets added to the backstack.
I try to work with **ModalDrawerSheet** and **NavigationDrawerItem**. I know that i need to add a state variable to the NavigationDrawer, who holds the HomeRoute as default, and then override this variable if the user clicks on one of the NavDrawer icons. But i cant find a way how to give the NavigationDrawerItem the information, that it belongs to a certain route. Is there any chance to get everything done only with these components? Or do i have to make the Items myself from dataClass and pass them to Drawersheet?

Here is the part of the code:

```
     @Composable
     fun MainCompose() {
     val navController = rememberNavController()
     val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
     val items = listOf(Icons.Default.Favorite, Icons.Default.Face, Icons.Default.Email)
     val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

     ***val currentScreen by remember(mutableStateOf("home")***


     ModalNavigationDrawer(
            drawerState = drawerState, gesturesEnabled = false,
            drawerContent = {

                ModalDrawerSheet(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f)) {
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))


                        NavigationDrawerItem(icon = { Icon(items[0], contentDescription = null) },
                            label = { Text(text = "Home") },
                            selected = false,
                            onClick = {
                                        scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
                                        navController.navigate("home"){
                                            popUpTo("home")
                                        }})
```

i want to tell the NavigationDrawerItem that if **currentScreen** has the same value like the route of the icon, that the click should be ignored. I hope i could express what the problem is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [LazyColumn](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyColumn(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) and then use the [items method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListScope).items(kotlin.collections.List,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2))  to create all `NavigationDrawerItem`s based on a List of Model classes.

Create a model class with the information for each item:

```kotlin
data class NavigationItemModel(
    val route: String,
    val icon: ImageVector,
    val label: @Composable () -> Unit,
)
```

Use the model classes to create `NavigationDrawerItem`:

```kotlin
val navItems = listOf(
    NavigationItemModel("home", { Text("home") }, Icons.Default.Home),
    // insert other routes
)

val currentRoute by remember { mutableStateOf("home") }

...

LazyColumn {
    items(navItems) { model ->
        NavigationDrawerItem(
            icon = { Icon(model.icon, contentDescription = null) },
            label = model.label,
            selected = (currentRoute == model.route),
            onClick = {
                // Check if already on this route
                if (currentRoute == model.route) {
                    return
                }
                scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
                navController.navigate("home"){
                    popUpTo("home")
                }
                // Update current route
                currentRoute = model.route
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it and everything works now. It was a good solution.